# Как в Omnipay обработать ответ от платежной системе?

Tags: php, laravel, платежи

Делаю магазин на Laravel, для работы с платежными системами использую библиотеку [Omnipay](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay) v3 + нужные драйвера (сейчас пробую делать для InterKassa) и wrapper для Laravel [barryvdh/laravel-omnipay](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-omnipay). 
Сделал процесс оформления заказа на своем сайте, переход на страницу платежной системе InterKassa, отплату в самой платежной системе, редирект назад в магазин на указанные страницы если платеж успешный или не успешный (returnUrl/cancelUrl в omnipay).
Также в настройках самой кассы InterKassa указал URL ("URL взаимодействия") для отправки на мой сайт  данных об произведенной оплаты - (notifyUrl в Omnipay).
Не могу разобраться как  можно обработать ответ от платежной системе, который платежная система присылает на мой notifyUrl и получить статус платежа, используя для этого библиотеку Omnipay и ее драйвера. Параметры ответа я то могу получить от платежки, например в массиве $_GET, (в Laravel $request->all()), но получается что от разных платежных система будут разные массивы, разные параметры.
В общем, можно ли этот ответ каким-то образом обработать с помощью драйвера Omnipay и получить унифицированный статус платежа, например как то так: 
if ($response->isSuccessful()) {//...}

В документации в примерах что то есть, но это или не то, или у я не так использую https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay#tldr . Здесь я так понимаю обработка ответа от платежки, сразу после отправки данных платежа..

Comment: я бы тут наверно, воспользовался паттерном [простая фабрика](http://designpatternsphp.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/Creational/SimpleFactory/README.html) и в конечном итоге получал бы унифицированый ответ, которое бы понимал ларавел

Comment: Ну я и спрашиваю, должно быть этот паттерн реализован в драйверах омнипея, только как это правильно использовать?!

Comment: это паттерн программирования, которым вы должны обработать ответ обоих платежных систем и далее из фабрики отдать ларавелу унифицированный ответ